# Path mapping not happening

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, postman

I'm using Java 17, Spring Boot 3 and Maven 3.9 for an API application. Right now, I'm trying to create a POST path and add new objects in the database (using MySQL). The database is created, and everything so far have been working properly.

It should be mapping a path to "localhost:3306/api/cadastrar-pj" where I should be able to POST new objects.
The Postman test returns the error: "Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/" to the body:

```
{
    "nome": "Armando A. M. Vidal",
    "email": "armandoamvidal@gmail.com",
    "senha": "123456",
    "cpf": "44433322211",
    "razaoSocial": "Armando Ltda",
    "cnpj": "12345678912345"
}
```

Here is the link to the GitHub repository: https://github.com/Armando-Vidal/ponto-inteligente-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the port 3306, that is where your database is being hosted, while Spring Boot by default hosts the server at port 8080.

If you access localhost:8080/api/cadastrar-pj it will work fine.

Comment: I got a 401 error on Postman. I tried adding the SecurityConfig class to create an equivalent of "security.basic.enabled=false" so it would accept any request but didn't work

Comment: Add the @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class }) annotation to your Main class, this will exclude the auto configuration class that Spring Security generates automatically. But if you have a custom Security Configuration class, the custom class will still be active, that's why you get the 401 error. So you gotta either delete your custom class or just comment it.

Comment: Just adding a comment in case someone else faces this 401 problem: in the config file I had to change the FilterChain to permit all requests and then I got a 403 problem, wich i corrected following the instructions on this link (using 5.1 section):
https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-fix-403-error#:~:text=This%20typically%20implies%20that%20the,t%20received%20the%20valid%20credentials.